# Javascript DOM addressing into a sub-window DOM element

Tags: dom

Given this screenshot of a Firefox DOM rendering, I'm interested in reading that highlighted element down a ways there and writing to the "hidden" attribute 3 lines above it.  I don't know the Javascript hierarchy nomenclature to traverse through that index "0" subwindow that shows in the first line under window indexed "3" which is the root context of my code's hierarchy.  That innerText element I'm after does not appear anywhere else in the DOM, at least that I can find...and I've looked and looked for it elsewhere.

Just looking at this DOM, I would say I could address that info as follows: `Window[3].Window[0].contentDocument.children[0].innerText` (no body, interestingly enough).

How this DOM came about is a little strange in that `Window[0]` is generated by the following code snippet located inside an onload event.  It makes a soft EMBED element, so that `Window[0]` and everything inside is transient.  FWIW, the EMBED element is simply a way for the script to offload the task of asynchronously pulling in the next .mp4 file name from the server while the previous .mp4 is playing so it will be ready instantly `onended`; no blocking necessary to get it.

```
          if (elmnt.contentDocument.body.children[1] == 'undefined' || elmnt.contentDocument.body.children[1] == null)
       {
               var mbed = document.createElement("EMBED");
               var attsrc =  document.createAttribute("src")
               mbed.setAttributeNode(attsrc);
               var atttyp =  document.createAttribute("type")
               mbed.setAttributeNode(atttyp);
               var attwid =  document.createAttribute("width")
               mbed.setAttributeNode(attwid);
               var atthei =  document.createAttribute("height")
               mbed.setAttributeNode(atthei);
               elmnt.contentDocument.body.appendChild(mbed);
       }
     elmnt.contentDocument.body.children[1].src=elmnt.contentDocument.body.children[0].currentSrc + '\?nextbymodifiedtime'
     elmnt.contentDocument.body.children[1].type='text/plain'
```

I know better than to think `Window[3].Window[0]......` is valid.  Can anyone throw me a clue how to address the DOM steps into the contentDocument of that `Window[0]`?  Several more of those soft Windows from soft EMBED elements will eventually exist as I develop the code, so keep that in mind.  Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`elmnt.contentWindow[0].document.children[0].innerText`  does the trick